# Send a ZPL data string to an IP address in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, zebra-printers, zpl

Using Ruby to send a series of data strings to a Zebra printer using its IP address.

Here's the Ruby code I've started with:

```
require 'socket'  
streamSock = TCPSocket.new( "127.0.0.1", 20000 )  
#streamSock.send( "Hello\n" )  
str = streamSock.recv( 100 )  
print str  
streamSock.close
```

I need to replace the `"Hello\n"` piece with ZPL (Zebra Print Language) code of this series of strings:

```
"^XA" +

"^FO50,50" +

"^A0N50,50" +

"^FDHello, World!^FS" +

"^XZ";
```

I've tried several ways of using #streamSock.send( "xxx" ) for each line - example: #streamSock.send( "^XA" ) - and then all the other string elements separately.

I tried a few variants of putting the entire string of ZPL codes into a single line, like

## streamSock.send( "^XA^FO50,50^A0N50,50^FDHello, World!^FS^XZ" )

The Zebra label printer does not respond. If I send the earlier series of strings to the printer as a text file using another utility, it prints fine.

Any ideas of what the Ruby code should be to make this work?

Comment: What model of printer is it?  Are you saying sending 'Hello\n' prints fine, but not the ZPL? If so, you may have your printer in line-print mode instead of ZPL. If it is in line print mode, it will not understand ZPL, and vice versa, they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I got it to work:
require 'socket'
hostname = '192.168.1.6'
port = 515
s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

s.puts "^XA^F100,100^BXN,10,200^FO150,120^FD01000012000000311081020122100000009^FS^XZ"

s.close

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
require 'socket'

streamSock = TCPSocket.new( "192.168.205.214", 6101 )
str = "^XA" + "^FO50,50" + "^A0N50,50" + "^FDHello World^FS" + "^XZ"
streamSock.send( str , 0)

streamSock.close
```